# jQuery Cycle Plugin: How to make the button link working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have used an external link on one of the buttons and it is not taking me to the link when the button text is clicked. Does anyone know how to fix this?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jetlag/Bjp5j/

HTML markup:

```
<div class="top button-area">
<div class="button button1">
    <div class="button-text">Button 1</div>
</div>
<div class="button button2">
    <div class="button-text"><a href="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/" target="_blank">Button 2</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="image-area">
<div class="image-section">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="image-section">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $this = $('.image-area');
  $this.cycle({
  fx: 'fade',
  speed: 'fast',
  timeout: 3000,
  pager: $this.parent().find('.button-area'),
  pauseOnPagerHover: true,
  pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
  pagerAnchorBuilder: function (idx, slide) {
    return $this.parent().find('.button-area .button:eq(' + idx + ')');
  }
});
```

Comment: can't use the element for both purposes...concept makes no sense. Explain in detail the behavior wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `.button-text a` element as a pager it removes the default behavior of the element (through `preventDefault()`). If the element has a `href` attribute you can still make it function as a link by using the following:

```
$('.button-text a')
    .filter('[href]').click(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
```

Here's a fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/Bjp5j/1/

This will allow for you to retain the functionality to switch the image when you hover over the button and also link to a specified URL.

*I must note that this behavior is a little bit strange! The user may attempt to click on the slideshow navigation to change the image and be redirected to another page. This would be an unexpected behavior and might be frustrating for the user.*

Comment: Yes your are right. This would be an unexpected behaviour and I've been thinking of elegantly tackling this issue. My program dynamically generates these buttons and allows users to create buttons as they need. So if they need buttons with dual functionality, they are still able to do it but I don't think most people will use it but it's still an option for them. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like an exception to it's standard usage and is probably going to be an afterthought. I wouldn't worry about it, but it's good that the functionality is there.